# A_2 muckenhoupt weights

Tags: harmonic-analysis

My question is easy.

Does A_2  muckenhoupt condition hold even if the weight $\omega$ is zero on some sets? What is the condition in this case?

I did not find a clear reference or explanation about this...

Comment: I think $A_p$ weights can only vanish on a set of measure zero. So maybe that renders your concern immaterial?

Comment: I agree with, you. I have the same opinion. Thanks